# Query from MySQL using a GROUP BY is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a single MySQL table of all the Vehicles, Makes and Engines for all the parts we carry.  I'm trying to make a cascading drop down search function using just PHP.  My script is failing on the second query;

```
SELECT model FROM veh_types WHERE make = $vehmakeA GROUP BY model
```

I am guessing it is failing on the GROUP BY clause.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

EDIT -------------
Here is more of my code.

```
echo "<p>VEHICLE MAKE"; 
    echo "<select name=\"vehmake\" id=\"vehmake\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\">";
    echo "<option value=\"--\">SELECT VEHICLE MAKE...</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"--\">SELECT VEHICLE MAKE 2...</option>";

    $queryModel = "SELECT make, model FROM veh_types WHERE make = $vehmakeA GROUP BY model";
    $resultModel = mysql_query($queryModel) or die(mysql_error());
    while($rowModel = mysql_fetch_array($resultModel)) {
        $vehmodel = $rowModel['model'];
        echo "<option value=\"$vehmodel\">$vehmodel</option>\n";    
    }

    echo "</select></p>";
```

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` tell you? I"m guessing it isn't failing on the `GROUP BY`, but on an unquoted string value of `$vehmakeA`.

Comment: `GROUP BY` might  not be doing what you expect here though. You have no aggregates (`SUM(),COUNT(),AVG(),MIN(),MAX(), etc`). Perhaps what you mean to do is `SELECT DISTINCT model...`

Comment: No error, just no results.  I'll add a more complete code sample to my original post.

Comment: pls show the database .........

Comment: Database is quite simple.  make, varchar, 100; model, varchar, 100; engine, varchar, 255.

Comment: Did you view your page source? Your error may have gotten eaten by the `<select>`.  It is likely you need to quote that variable `WHERE make = '$vehmakeA'` (and please protect it from SQL injection)

Comment: Ah... Thank you, thank you, thank you...  A combination of answers solved my problem.  I changed it from GROUP BY to DISTINCT and added some single quotes around my variable and it works!!!  Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: I've got my POST data wrapped by filter_var.  Think it's enough?

Comment: filter_var works. You should accept an answer to close this thread.

Comment: Neither of the answers below worked for my particular issue.  I answered my own question based on comments above, but it won't let me accept is as the answer for two days...

Answer (score 1):

The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

> SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name) FROM table_name
>   WHERE column_name operator value GROUP BY column_name

**Aggregate (GROUP BY) Functions**

```
Name    Description

AVG()   Return the average value of the argument
BIT_AND()   Return bitwise and
BIT_OR()    Return bitwise or
BIT_XOR()   Return bitwise xor
COUNT(DISTINCT) Return the count of a number of different values
COUNT() Return a count of the number of rows returned
GROUP_CONCAT()  Return a concatenated string
MAX()   Return the maximum value
MIN()   Return the minimum value
STD()   Return the population standard deviation
STDDEV_POP()    Return the population standard deviation
STDDEV_SAMP()   Return the sample standard deviation
STDDEV()    Return the population standard deviation
SUM()   Return the sum
VAR_POP()   Return the population standard variance
VAR_SAMP()  Return the sample variance
VARIANCE()  Return the population standard variance
```

ref:[link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just put together what I think your table looks like, and this query works for me:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `veh_types` (
      `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `make` varchar(100) default '0',
      `model` varchar(100) default '0',
      `submodel` varchar(100) default '0',
      `type` varchar(100) default '0',
      UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `veh_types` VALUES (1, 'Ford', 'Ranger', 'EX', 'Truck');
    INSERT INTO `veh_types` VALUES (2, 'Ford', 'Focus', 'EX', 'Car');
    INSERT INTO `veh_types` VALUES (3, 'Honda', 'Civic', 'EX', 'Car');
    INSERT INTO `veh_types` VALUES (4, 'Honda', 'Accord', 'LX', 'Car');
    INSERT INTO `veh_types` VALUES (5, 'Chevy', 'S10', 'LS', 'Truck');

    SELECT model
    FROM veh_types 
    WHERE make = 'Ford'
    GROUP BY model;
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of answers solved my problem. I changed it from GROUP BY to DISTINCT and added some single quotes around my variable and it works!!! Thanks to all for your help! Looking back, both answers were from Michael Berkowski.  Thanks Michael!